# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to code a program that eliminates some of the connected components and keep the rest.
However, at some point in the code, the program exits with error message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

I have narrowed down the error to the statement: "destinationImage.at(row, column) = labeledImage.at(row, column);" using the checkpoints you'll find the code below.

I have tried all the solution I found, especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140425/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-in-pixel-manipulation), with no luck.

Please Help!

One more thing, the program reads the image correctly but does not show the original image as per the code. Instead, it prints a message "init done 
opengl support available". Is this normal? Does the implementation of the imshow take place at the end of the program with no errors?

```
/* Goal is to find all related components, eliminate secondary objects*/

#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

//Declaring variables
Mat originalImage;
int conComponentsCount;
int primaryComponents;

//Declaring constants
const char* keys =
{
    "{@image|../data/sample.jpg|image for converting to a grayscale}"  
};

//Functions prototypes, used to be able to define functions AFTER the "main" function
Mat BinarizeImage (Mat &, int thresh);
int AverageCCArea(Mat & CCLabelsStats,int numOfLabels, int minCCSize);
bool ComponentIsIncludedCheck (int ccArea, int referenceCCArea);

//Program mainstream============================================
int main (int argc, const char **argv)
{
    //Waiting for user to enter the required path, default path is defined in "keys" string
    CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, keys);
    string inputImage = parser.get<string>(0);

    //Reading original image
    //NOTE: the program MUST terminate or loop back if the image was not loaded; functions below use reference to matrices and references CANNOT be null or empty.
    originalImage = imread(inputImage.c_str(), IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);// or: imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
    cout << " 1) Loading image done!" << endl;//CHECKPOINT
    if (originalImage.empty())
    {
        cout << "Nothing was loaded!";
        return -1; //terminating program with error feedback
    }

    cout << " 2) Checking for null Image done!" << endl;//CHECKPOINT

    namedWindow("Original Image", 0);
    imshow("Original Image", originalImage);

    cout << " 3) Showing ORIGINAL image done!" << endl;//CHECKPOINT

    //Image Binarization; connectedcomponents function only accepts binary images.
    int threshold=100; //Value chosen empirically.
    Mat binImg = BinarizeImage(originalImage, threshold);

    cout << " 4) Binarizing image done!" << endl;//CHECKPOINT

    //Finding the number of connected components and generating the labeled image.
    Mat labeledImage; //Image with connected components labeled.
    Mat stats, centroids; //Statistics of connected image's components.
    conComponentsCount = connectedComponentsWithStats(binImg, labeledImage, stats, centroids, 4, CV_16U);

    cout << " 5) Connecting pixels done!" << endl;//CHECKPOINT

    //Creating a new matrix to include the final image (without secondary objects)
    Mat destinationImage(labeledImage.size(), CV_16U);
    //Calculating the average of the labeled image components areas
    int ccSizeIncluded = 1000;
    int avgComponentArea = AverageCCArea(stats, conComponentsCount, ccSizeIncluded);

    cout << " 6) Calculating components avg area done!" << endl;//CHECKPOINT

    //Criteria for component sizes
    for (int row = 0; row <= labeledImage.rows; row++)
    {
        cout << " 6a) Starting rows loop iteration # " << row+1 << " done!" << endl;//CHECKPOINT
        for (int column = 0; column <= labeledImage.cols; column++)
        {
            //Criteria for component sizes
            int labelValue = labeledImage.at<int>(row, column);
            if (ComponentIsIncludedCheck (stats.at<int>(labelValue, CC_STAT_AREA), avgComponentArea))
            {
                //Setting pixel value to the "destinationImage"
                destinationImage.at<int>(row, column) = labeledImage.at<int>(row, column);

                cout << " 6b) Setting pixel (" << row << "," << column << ") done!" << endl;//CHECKPOINT
            }
            else
                cout << " 6c) Pixel (" << row << "," << column << ") Skipped!" << endl;//CHECKPOINT
        }
        cout << " 6d) Row " << row << " done!" << endl;//CHECKPOINT
    }

    cout << " 7) Showing FINAL image done!" << endl;//CHECKPOINT

    namedWindow("Final Image", 0);
    imshow("Final Image", destinationImage);

    cout << " 8) Program done!" << endl;//CHECKPOINT

    waitKey (0);
}

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Mat BinarizeImage (Mat & originalImg, int threshold=100) //default value of threshold of grey content.
{
    // Binarization of image to be used in connectedcomponents function. 
    Mat bw = threshold < 128 ? (originalImg < threshold) : (originalImg > threshold);
    return bw;
}

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
int AverageCCArea(Mat & CCLabelsStats,int numOfLabels, int minCCSize) //calculates the average area of connected components without components smaller than minCCSize pixels..... reference is used to improve performance, passing-by-reference does not require copying the matrix to this function.
{
    int average;

    for (int i=1; i<=numOfLabels; i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int validComponentsCount = numOfLabels - 1;
        if (CCLabelsStats.at<int>(i, CC_STAT_AREA) >= minCCSize)
        {
            sum += CCLabelsStats.at<int>(i, CC_STAT_AREA);
        }
        else
        {
            validComponentsCount--;
        }
        average = sum / (validComponentsCount);
    }
    return average;
}

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
bool ComponentIsIncludedCheck (int ccArea, int referenceCCArea)
{
    if (ccArea >= referenceCCArea)
    {
        return true; //Component should be included in the destination image
    }
    else
    {
        return false; //Component should NOT be included in the destination image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
for (int row = 0; row <= labeledImage.rows; row++)
```

to this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < labeledImage.rows; row++)
```

and this:

```
 for (int column = 0; column <= labeledImage.cols; column++)
```

to this:

```
 for (int column = 0; column < labeledImage.cols; column++)
```

any good?

(remember that in C++ we start counting from 0, so if e.g. `labeledImage.cols == 10`, the last column is the one with the index 9)

Comment: The problem persists.
the loop iterated 32 times with result :" 6b) Setting pixel (0,31) done!"

no result was " 6c) Pixel (row,column) Skipped!"

Comment: well a segmentation fault in your case essentially means that you're trying to access some non-existent element in one of your matrices. Within your loop you are also accessing `destinationImage`, `labeledImage` and `stats`. Try printing their size and the requested indices for each iteration BEFORE every attempt to access them. The last printed values should be the ones causing the problem.

Comment: I have tried placing the cout in the inner loop before the matrices were accessed and printed the sizes each time, they were fixed ![see this](s29.postimg.org/64wvpjcfb/smaller_Image_SS.png). I changed the sample picture, the procedure would not iterate at all, segmentation error shows before the loops are entered! ![like this](s2.postimg.org/ozthvbi9l/larger_Image_Screenshot.png).

Comment: The problem is in your loop and I believe it is here: `stats.at<int>(labelValue, CC_STAT_AREA)` what are the values of `labelValue` and CC_STAT_AREA for each iteration?? The size of stats is 5x931 so whenever `labelValue` is bigger than 4 you'll get a segmentation fault.. I bet that `labeledImage.at<int>(0,32)` is bigger than 4..

Comment: I have changed the "CC_STAT_AREA" to be the row value in every location it is used, now the program works to pixel (3, 495) then gives the segmentation error.   In a different trial, I removed all of the "for loop" and viewed the labeledImage, it was all-black!! I used a large image, the segmentation fault showed after image binarization!

Comment: segmentation faults means that you're trying to access something non-existent in your case. So in put a `cout` in all indices an in all sizes in all loops to locate the index which is out of range.